# UILabel alignment in chat bubble (UICollectionViewCell)

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, chat

I'm trying to align a UILabel inside a UICollectionViewCell like Whatsapp, Telegram, etc... Last line aligned to the left of the hour label, the others that ends on top of it.

I've tried adding at the end of the text some transparent characters and it worked until I tried some emojis; extra characters changed emoji code.
This is a sample of the code I'm using with TTTAttributedLabel for links detection.

```
let text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, enim apeirian his cu. Saperet interesset ex cum, ut per altera quodsi causae."
let endTransparentText = "aaaaa"
let showingText = text + endTransparentText
cell.lblMessage.setText(showingText) { (attributedString) -> NSMutableAttributedString? in
                    attributedString?.addAttribute(kCTForegroundColorAttributeName as String, value: UIColor.clear, range: NSMakeRange((showingText.characters.count-endTransparentText.characters.count), endTransparentText.characters.count))
                    return attributedString
                }
```

Someone had to deal with this problem?

Comment: Update your question with what you have tried so far.

Comment: Internal string representation is UTF-16 entities. So each symbol can occupy more than one character. Emojis length is 32 bit or 2 character. Apple docs say:

> "If you need to access string objects character by character, you must understand the Unicode character encoding, specifically issues related to composed character sequences"

https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve this label alignment without "cheating" with extra characters?